# How to run a script when I connect a device?

Tags: udev

new Linux user here (Ubuntu 12.04)...  I've been looking on google and found some scripts that would make what I'm about to ask easier but what I would like to do is write a script that automatically opens terminal and runs the command 'easytether connect' when I connect my phone to the computer...  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you try Googling for udev rules?  Lots of tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the `udev` attributes for target device (if you know it). Example:

   ```
   udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyACM0
   ```

   Or monitor `udev` events (then plug your device):

   ```
   udevadm monitor --environment --udev
   ```
2. Use specific attributes to match target device and Create new `udev` rules file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`. Use `ACTION=="add"` to match device added event and `RUN+="..."` to run needed script. Example

   ```
   ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="eth0", RUN+="/usr/bin/ethtool -s eth0 wol d"
   ```

References:

- [Udev rule cheatsheet](http://www.farseer.cn/cheatsheet/2013/11/24/udev-rule-cheatsheet/)
- [Writing udev rules](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)
- [`man udev`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/udev.7.html)